# How to filter DOM elements that are either <div>s or <input>s using a single jQuery selector?

Tags: jquery, dom, jquery-selectors

How to filter DOM elements that are either `<div>`s or `<input>`s using a single jQuery selector?  For example, if I have the following HTML document:

```
<!DOCTYPE html ...>
<html xmlns="...">
<head>...</head>
<body>
    <input value=""/>
    <div></div>
    <select><option value="hi">ho</option></select>
</body>
</html>
```

I would like to use something like `$('body > ???')` to select the `<input>` and the `<div>`, but not the `<select>`.

Comment: Do you only want to select `<input>` and `<div>` tags that are direct descendants of the `<body>` tag, or any `<input>` and `<div>` tags in the whole document?

Comment: Direct descendants of body only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
$("body > input, body > div")
```

Comment: Why use `body > input` and not just `input`?

Comment: "@God is good" OP needs to filter direct descendants of body not all occurencies - check the question comments. I hope you will reconsider your downvote.

Answer (score 5):

It's simple as `$('input, div')`.

Comment: Seems silly to list all the elements to select. better to select all and tell it which to not select? like my answer

Comment: No, that's the way to do it. Think of it as CSS selectors. Also it's way more performant and clearer to read.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("body *").not("select").each(function() {
  // code here
});
```

Something like that should work a treat.

See this example - http://jsfiddle.net/UeHTV/

Comment: Thomas: In the real HTML document I'm processing, there are lots of elements that are not inputs, divs or selects. The example I gave was... just an example.

Comment: Hi @Eduardo Leóny, question is, are there more that you wont be selecting? or more you will? former, use mine, latter, use @Raveren

Comment: I think a whitelist makes sense from a maintenance perspective - if he decides to add 1500 lines of new HTML to the page, he doesn't need to check all his new code for new tags to eliminate.  Pick the tags you want and you don't have additional maintenance.

Comment: In that case I think @Raveren would be the best option @Surreal Dreams